# Is there test status property in NUnit 3.0?

Tags: testing, automation, nunit, nunit-3.0

In NUnit v. < 3.0 there was TestContext class and there was a property that could tell us a status of the previously run test.

To access the property we could use `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status`

Now in NUnit 3.0 there is no property as `Status`! So all my tests need to be changed.

**My question is the next:** is it possible to get test status in NUnit 3.0 as it was possible to do in previous version?

**Interesting thing**: there was class **TestStatus** with properties: `Passed, Failed` etc. and we used it to compare with current status. This class is present in NUnit 3.0!

**My code:**

```
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
{
    //Be happy if it works)
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**I searched deeper and found the solution!**

Now in NUnit 3.0 we have to change this:

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status
```

To this:

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status
```